# Replace Number with Text

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm new to the coding world, i need your help in creating a batch or VB script to replace a number with static text; 
I receive the below file

[image]

where I need to replace the "TP"and "123456678" with Static text "LL", "ONRECORD" after comparing the second file

[image]

row numbers.Anybody has gone through this requirement?

I do not have any code as am a new bee and here to learn.

Thank you.

```
> File-1
099,3,IZM,97101122400,,PAT,HYANGLI PARK,1100/,TP,98379108610,4000.00,A
099,3,IZM,97101122426,,PAT,NAWAZ SHARIFF,1100/,TP,98639269764,1500.00,A
099,3,IZM,97101122624,,PAT,ABDUL WAHID,1100/,TP,98409328386,6500.00,A
099,3,IZM,97101122699,,PAT,SHINE C B,1100/,TP,96805840301,1500.00,A
099,3,IZM,97101122715,,PAT,HUPING LI,1100/,TP,98217686108,1500.00,A
099,3,IZM,97101123051,,PAT,CHERYL G P,1100/,TP,97970379422,2000.00,A
> 

> File-2 
    > DER,000330,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    > DER,000333,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    > DER,000339,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    > DER,000377,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    > DER,000462,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    > DER,000755,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    > DER,000820,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    > DER,001055,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
```

[samplecodepic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djbg1.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures, instead insert plain text in your quesion.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q50203863.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q50203863_2.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

:: Retrieve line numbers from file2.

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=," %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 REM token 1 (%%a) must be "DER", token 2 (%%b) contains line number
 REM set 'line' to zero-suppressed line number, then #linenumber to 'Y'
 IF "%%a"=="DER" SET /a line=1%%b %% 100000&SET "#!line!=Y"
)

(
REM number each line in [] with 'find'
REM then tokenise - %%a gets the number, %%b the line-contents
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN ('type "%filename1%"^|find /n /v ""') DO (
 IF DEFINED #%%a (
  REM process if selected
  FOR /f "tokens=1-9,*delims=," %%g IN ("%%b") DO (
   REM Tokenise to %%g..%%p.
   REM if %%n is "TP" then replace else report
   IF "%%n"=="TP" (
    ECHO %%g,%%h,%%i,%%j,,%%k,%%l,%%m,LL,ONRECORD,%%p
   ) ELSE (
    ECHO ERROR - line %%a does NOT contain TP IN required column LINE OMITTED
   )
  )
 ) ELSE IF "%%b" neq "" (
  REM IF NOT selected, simply regurgitate it unless empty
  ECHO %%b
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.
I used files named `q50203863.txt` `q50203863_2.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Most of the how-it-works is contained in comments.

For lack of specification otherwise, I chose to check replacement of `TP`.

Your examples have column 5 empty (two successive commas) It's important to draw attention to such matters. If column 5 is not **always** empty, then a different approach needs to be adopted as the `for/f` tokenising is performed against delimiter-sequences, not individual delimiters.

---

Debug methodology:

Given that you are using a small sample of data for each file for testing, then the line numbers in the second file must correspond to the lines required to be changed in the first. In the data posted, lines 300, 333 etc. are selected but the sample data contains only 6 lines which would be numbered 1-6, hence the test will not find the required lines and simply regurgitate the original file.

Possibility 1:

If you are using `cygwin` then the cygwin installer prioritises the *nix version of `find` over the Windows version.

To invoke the windows version, you need to specify the absolute path to `find.exe` which is normally `C:\Windows\System32\find.exe` or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\find.exe`

If that doesn't cure the problem, then we need to investigate further:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q50203863.txt"
SET "filename2=%sourcedir%\q50203863_2.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

:: Retrieve line numbers from file2.

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=," %%a IN ("%filename2%") DO (
 REM token 1 (%%a) must be "DER", token 2 (%%b) contains line number
 REM set 'line' to zero-suppressed line number, then #linenumber to 'Y'
 
 ECHO "%%a" "%%b"
 
 IF "%%a"=="DER" SET /a line=1%%b %% 100000&SET "#!line!=Y"
)
REM The next line should list all of the lines-required-to-be-changed
REM in the format "#linenumber=Y"
SET #

(
REM number each line in [] with 'find'
REM then tokenise - %%a gets the number, %%b the line-contents
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN ('type "%filename1%"^|find /n /v ""') DO (
 IF DEFINED #%%a (
  REM process if selected
  ECHO Line %%a found for analysis>con
  FOR /f "tokens=1-9,*delims=," %%g IN ("%%b") DO (
   REM Tokenise to %%g..%%p.
   REM if %%n is "TP" then replace else report
   IF "%%n"=="TP" (
    ECHO Line %%a has TP in required column and should be changed>con
    ECHO %%g,%%h,%%i,%%j,,%%k,%%l,%%m,LL,ONRECORD,%%p
   ) ELSE (
    ECHO Line %%a does not have TP in required column>con
    ECHO ERROR - line %%a does NOT contain TP IN required column LINE OMITTED
   )
  )
 ) ELSE IF "%%b" neq "" (
  REM IF NOT selected, simply regurgitate it unless empty
  ECHO %%b
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

PAUSE

GOTO :EOF
```

The new lines ending in `>con` (redirect to the console, overriding the redirection to "%outfile%") should report on any "hits"

The `pause` line is only required if you are using point-click-and-giggle to execute the batch. It keeps the window open so that reports can be seen.

[201805170055] I've added a new line, `ECHO "%%a" "%%b"` in the second `for /f` loop to display the contents of the columns of interest. This should show a list of lines like `"DER" "000002"`. Please describe results shown.

Comment: thank you @magoo for the quick code..i will check and come back to you with results :)

Comment: Hi @magoo, the column 5 is empty and it needs to have two successive commas. I have put the  actual file content as i had shared as a screenshot earlier to have a clear picture; I tried the above batch..seems like something is missing :(

Comment: column5: I simply observed that column5 is empty. The issue is whether *any* column may have data *sometimes* but not *always*. Sadly, your posted data appears to want to alter lines 330,333, 339 etc - but these are not available in your data sample from the first file. I altered these to suit the restricted size of the data you've provided (posts simply need to have *adequate* data, not hundreds of lines.) AFAICS, the process replaced data in the lines specified. "Something is missing" doesn't explain much - what is "missing" from your result?

Comment: @mangoo, the required changes are not happening and output file is generated similar to the source file, TP & ID numbers are not changed to LL & ONRECORD.

Comment: I've added some debug code. BTW - the original poster receives *all* responses (comments or solutions) automatically, and people posting solutions receive comment/alteration notifications automatically also. No need for @-addressing in those cases.

Comment: > I think the File-1 is not picking the line numbers from File-2 
    DER,000**330**,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    DER,000**333**,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    DER,000**339**,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    DER,000**377**,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    DER,000**462**,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    DER,000**755**,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    DER,000**820**,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID
    DER,00**1055**,CAD-SEC-10,10-ID NUMBER IS NOT VALID

Comment: does the `set #` command produce any results? It should show `#330=Y` etc.

Comment: sorry i was away. today i tried it unfortunately it does not produce any result.

Comment: set # command produce result now :) how can I get this done automatically please? Can we also get log file mentioning the changes if possible please. Thank you very much.

Comment: The changed file should appear as the file specified as `outfile` (it should have the same name as the input filename). The lines ending `>con` should provide a processing report. Replace `>con` with `>>someotherfilename` to redirect that report to a file. Note `>>` in this case, not `>` as you need to *append* to a file - appending to the console is meaningless..) If you execute `fc inputfilename outputfilename >reportfilename` then a report of the differences between the two files will be generated. That report shows the changed line from the first file and the result in the second.

Comment: I am getting the required output file if I manually put the line numbers SET #368=Y
SET #711=Y what if I need to get it automatically without inserting any line numbers to the batch file manually?

Comment: You said that the `set #` was reporting the `#*` values found, I can only assume that those numbers are correct, as extracted from the file you nominate. Since setting `#*` manually also apparently produces the required results, I can see no reason why, having set the values as reported, the second part wouldn't process the file correctly. Need more information if this is failing.

Comment: If I **SET #%%=Y** will it take the row # by it's own?

Comment: I have no idea to what you are referring. If you manually establish `#123` as any value, then since `#123` exists, this should make the change provided `TP` is in the correct column in line `123`, otherwise it should report `ERROR - line 123 does NOT contain TP IN required column LINE OMITTED` - as it should for every other line where `#*` is established, which you appear to have confirmed with your comment on  May 25 at 12:43.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine, however I am trying to get the output file without any manual intervention, currently i need to enter the row numbers in the batch file to get the required data manually(as shown in the pic) **samplecodepic1**, how can the code just find all the line numbers when i run the batch without me entering the line numbers. I'm almost there.

Comment: You have said that `set #` correctly reported the line numbers to be selected. Those values are set in the environment (unless specifically cleared) until the end of the batch, so all that's required is to execute the `FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN (...` part directly after the `set #` line. Remember, the `set #` line is simply reporting which lines ahve been selected for debugging purposes.